# ubuntu 17.04 can't scan any wifi with Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)

Tags: wireless, 16.10, 17.04, intel-wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 but I can only use wired network, the wireless is disabled.
My script is as follow:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Jul 2017 11:26 SGT +0800

Booted last: 21 Jul 2017 00:00 SGT +0800

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-59-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 19:38:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3884]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b57e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04d9:a19f Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6447104  0
iwlmvm                360448  0
mac80211              757760  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              581632  4 wl,iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    16384  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  3 nouveau,i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.18.80  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 172.19.23.255
        inet6 fe80::b33:f451:8693:934f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 79637  bytes 33401087 (33.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41476  bytes 5009444 (5.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 116617  bytes 7674805 (7.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 116617  bytes 7674805 (7.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.19.16.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
155.69.3.8      172.19.16.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp4s0
172.19.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search eee.ntu.edu.sg

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       764     1  0 Jul20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp4s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ebffc8e8-1393-3283-a233-9bee9ffd5582
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ebffc8e8-1393-3283-a233-9bee9ffd5582 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.19.18.80/21
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.19.16.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 155.69.3.8/32, nh = 172.19.16.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             155.69.3.9
IP4.DNS[2]:                             155.69.3.8
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          eee.ntu.edu.sg
IP4.WINS[1]:                            155.69.5.154
IP4.WINS[2]:                            155.69.5.54
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1500680321
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 172.19.16.254
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 172.19.18.80
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = eee.ntu.edu.sg
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 172.19.23.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 155.69.3.9 155.69.3.8
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 79302
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       netbios_name_servers = 155.69.5.154 155.69.5.54
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.248.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 172.19.16.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 155.69.3.8
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::b33:f451:8693:934f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.8.0-59-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               22.361476.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Singapore (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp4s0    no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      16   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      9   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      19   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)
      4   APs on   Frequency:5.26 GHz (Channel 52)
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.3 GHz (Channel 60)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.56 GHz (Channel 112)
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.745 GHz
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.765 GHz
      3   APs on   Frequency:5.785 GHz

wlp3s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'WLPS' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"WLPS"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000da7789b1a5
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2008ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Delta-Office' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Delta-Office"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000dfe27f5e1f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2096ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          ........

          Cell 69 - Address: <MAC 'eduroam' [AC69]>
                    Channel:157
                    Frequency:5.785 GHz
                    Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eduroam"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000001d2c75319
                    Extra: Last beacon: 292ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     0ADAE750C888A523D63D8B5
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.8.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-59-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     8CB024DCE8CBAD06752D324
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-59-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     9AF49B72127065FCF655D6A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-59-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-IWL6000G2B_UCODE_API_MAX.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-lc-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-lc-a0--24.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--24.ucode
srcversion:     E7651FD3D9AF45F96CD8B2E
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-59-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     46F63B461AA5E38D042F531
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 8
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  167.496530] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[  168.202206] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  170.412134] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[  170.464909] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  171.016624] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[  171.203672] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[  172.102277] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete

########## wireless info END ############
```

Ubuntu16.10 can't scan any wifi with Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78, please assist?

I have now upgraded to 17.04 and have the same issue.

Comment: This is about 16.10 which is EOL. Please upgrade to 17.04.

Comment: Hi ubashu, I upgrade to 17.04, but meet same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the drivers, but with a hard block.

Run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.