# Intel Corporation: Unknown

Tags: drivers, system-installation, intel

I assume the issue is with my WiFi drivers as I cannot connect to 5Ghz Wifi BUT I can on 2.4 Ghz one.

The drivers I need to use [Intel® Wireless-AC 9462](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) (tried to install them but nothing changed)

[image: Also I can only see this on Software & Updates]

Here is my report that will help you help me:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 25 Mar 2020 13:58 GMT +0000

Booted last: 25 Mar 2020 00:00 GMT +0000

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a4]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [1462:7b17]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1462:1720 Micro Star International 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2516:0011  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1b1c:0c0b Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1b1c:0c18 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1038:1720 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
iwlmvm                417792  0
mac80211              778240  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               376832  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              688128  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
compat                 16384  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
wmi                    32768  3 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eno2' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.15/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 85778sec preferred_lft 85778sec
    inet6 fe80::7889:a0bd:8809:1312/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

wlo1      no wireless extensions.

eno2      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.15 metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1118     1  0 13:48 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.3.0-42-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     JohnStreet
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4a1c26e6-a915-495c-b1dc-2d56b6a2c5db
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     72 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.15/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             194.168.4.100
IP4.DNS[2]:                             194.168.8.100
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = pirkos
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.15
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1585230509
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       domain_name_servers = 194.168.4.100 194.168.8.100
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7889:a0bd:8809:1312/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4a1c26e6-a915-495c-b1dc-2d56b6a2c5db | JohnStreet

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.2-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno2' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/eno2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID        BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  IN-USE 
JohnStreet  <MAC 'JohnStreet' [AN1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  130 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  yes     *      

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-ubuntu-fan.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices+=interface-name:fan-*

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JohnStreet 5G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JohnStreet 5G | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=JohnStreet 5G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JohnStreet]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JohnStreet | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=JohnStreet
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

global
country GB: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

wlo1      no frequency information.

eno2      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

wlo1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno2      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     03FD107A3ACB22BC7B9B05B
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,compat,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           iwlmvm
vermagic:       5.3.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/updates/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
srcversion:     2CBDE2280305E453FCD816B
depends:        cfg80211,compat,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.3.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-SoSnj-a0-gf4-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-55.ucode
srcversion:     429405ECF8888645E7117B9
depends:        compat,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.3.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           xvt_default_mode:xVT is the default operation mode (default: false) (bool)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: true (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_msix:Disable MSI-X and use MSI instead (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
version:        iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     85C762B91466B7F2749B25C
depends:        compat
retpoline:      Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.3.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
debug: 0
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
disable_msix: N
enable_ini: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3
xvt_default_mode: N

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf]
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf]
options nouveau modeset=0

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   21.034295] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
[   21.052201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   21.053275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[   21.055204] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[   21.055205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[   21.055206] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[   21.055206] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[   21.055207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[   21.055207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[   21.055207] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[   21.055208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[   21.055208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[   21.055209] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[   21.055209] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[   21.055210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[   21.055210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[   21.055211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   21.055212] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   21.055367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   21.055377] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[   21.061112] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   21.107781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: <MAC 'wlo1' [IF2]>
[   21.151561] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   21.420059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   22.169590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
[   22.171106] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[   25.404719] wlo1: authenticate with <MAC 'JohnStreet' [AN1]>
[   25.412499] wlo1: send auth to <MAC 'JohnStreet' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[   25.436095] wlo1: authenticated
[   25.438328] wlo1: associate with <MAC 'JohnStreet' [AN1]> (try 1/3)
[   25.444098] wlo1: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'JohnStreet' [AN1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   25.445791] wlo1: associated
[   25.480908] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

I tried everything I could for it but nothing.
I hope this will be solved like this guy's issue: [ubuntu 17.04 can't scan any wifi with Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938245/ubuntu-17-04-cant-scan-any-wifi-with-intel-corporation-device-24fd-rev-78)

This is the output after `dmesg | grep iwl` from the answer below

```
[   38.322460] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   38.322460] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
[   38.354367] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   38.356714] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[   38.358577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[   38.358578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[   38.358578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[   38.358579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[   38.358579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[   38.358580] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[   38.358580] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[   38.358580] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[   38.358581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[   38.358581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[   38.358582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[   38.358582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[   38.358583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[   38.358584] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   38.358584] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   38.358749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   38.358764] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[   38.366075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   38.414069] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 4c:1d:96:0e:5e:84
[   38.458365] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   38.916589] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   39.736608] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
[   39.738091] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Here is the screenshot from `nmcli device wifi list`
[image: screenshot]

Comment: That information is wrong in GUI. All is OK with the drivers. Everyday somone asks this.

Comment: so why I cannot connect to 5Ghz Wifi then?

Comment: Which 5 GHz channel you are trying to connect to?

Comment: I spitted my WiFi channels for better performance (this is what I got suggested by the provider) and I actually see the difference on my macbook with 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz.. The problem I can connect to 2.4 but not 5 Ghz

Comment: So which channel? Maybe the channel is not allowed by regulatory setting, etc.

Comment: it's called JohnStreet 5G (it's again a different wifi connection) Do I need to connect to it first and then create the network report?

Comment: We just want to know what channel it's on; 36? 152? 65? If you are not able to find out from other devices on the network, then tell us the frequency, like 5.745 GHz. Also, is *GB* your correct regulatory domain?

Comment: Sorry @chili555 Channel 44, Signal -52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be certain that you have the latest firmware:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

I will continue this answer after we gather the results above.

**EDIT**: Your wireless device clearly sees the 5 gHz access point now. We notice that the encryption method is shown as WPA and WPA2 mixed mode.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6, 11, 44 or 52, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Now are you able to connect to the 5 gHz access point?

Comment: I added the output on the question above @chili555

Comment: Please also add the result of: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: just added it @chili555

Comment: Your wireless device clearly sees the 5 gHz access point now. Please see my edit in a few moments.

Comment: Nice! 
This is what worked for me:
WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.